# Battery charge simulation not clipping properly as it iterates

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, core-language, simulation

My code for simulating a batterylevel-state throughout a year in 15min-steps doesn't work.

There is a certain list-inputs which simulates the charge state and the batterylevel-state, additionally maximum capacity and minimum capacity(because of discharge-depth) and L as start charging state

```
maxk=10;
mink=2;
L=5;
chargelevel= {-0.1,-0.1,-0.2, ...(more than 35000 other positive/negative values)...,-0.2,-0.1};
batterylevel=Table[L, {n, 0, 35040}]
```

which is used by

```
For[i = 1, i < 35040, i++,
  Which[mink <= (batterylevel[[i - 1]] + chargelevel[[i]]) <= maxk,
    batterylevel[[i]] = (batterylevel[[i - 1]] + chargelevel[[i]]), 
    batterylevel[[i]] <= mink, batterylevel[[i - 1]] = mink, 
    batterylevel[[i]] >= maxk, batterylevel[[i - 1]] = maxk
    ];];
ListPlot[batterylevel]
```

batterylevel`

The function should be working like this:
The loop defines that i is running over the whole thing 35040 times and the batterylevel from step `i-1` should be summed up with the chargelevel from step `i`.
If the charge state reaches or falls below `2kWh`, it should stay at `mink=2kWh` and don't add negative chargelevel-rates anymore and go on with looping until there is a positive chargelevel, then it should add chargerates again and load the battery until `maxk=10kWh` and then stop again at `10kWh` and go on with looping. When it reaches negative states, it should discharge again until `2` and so on.

So far i successfully modeled this thing in excel and it worked flawlessly.
The crazy thing is that it worked yesterday after trying it a few times and it matched with the result in excel.

Today since i loaded the same notebook (!) it doesn't give me the same output anymore because according to the batterylevel-output it discharges till or below `2` (since it's more likely to reach `mink=2` first) and then it starts at `L=5` again, adding or substracting the rates according to the chargelevel. The same happens when reaching `maxk=10`, it just jumps back to `L=5`. It doesn't jump with the chargelevel-list though.

According to `PlotList` it looks like this, where you can clearly see that it jumps back:
[image: PlotList[batterylevel] and batterylevel]

I even tried to rewrite the loop with while and the conditional with If and Switch, where i get the same result (although If is made like the one in Excel).

Can somebody help me out with this please?

Answer (score 12):

Your code shows you are somewhat confused about the indices. Here is some code that is more *Mathematica* idiomatic and which makes keeping the indices straight much easier. I am running the simulation with a 24 hour step to cut down the data plotted. Should work just a well with your time step.

```
maxk = 10;
mink = 2;
steps = 365;
batterylevel = ConstantArray[0, steps];
batterylevel[[1]] = 5;

SeedRandom[7]; chargelevel = RandomReal[{-.75, .75}, steps];

Do[Module[{next},
   next = batterylevel[[i - 1]] + chargelevel[[i]];
   Which[
    mink < next < maxk, batterylevel[[i]] = next,
    next <= mink, batterylevel[[i]] = mink,
    next >= maxk, batterylevel[[i]] = maxk]],
  {i, 2, steps}];

ListPlot[batterylevel]
```

[image: plot]

You can see the clipping at 2 and 10 is now handled correctly.

#### Update 1

Using the built-in *Mathematica* function [`Clip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html), your simulation can be reduced to

```
Do[
  batterylevel[[i]] = Clip[batterylevel[[i - 1]] + chargelevel[[i]], {mink, maxk}],
  {i, 2, steps}]
```

#### Update 2

As you become more experienced with *Mathematica*, you will come to appreciate that your simulation can be expressed even more concisely. In *Mathematica* there is no need to create a `batterylevel` array.

```
SeedRandom[7];
 With[{maxk = 10, mink = 2, initk = 5, steps = 365},
   Module[{chargelevel},
    chargelevel = RandomReal[{-.75, .75}, steps];
    ListPlot[FoldList[Clip[#1 + #2, {mink, maxk}] &, initk, chargelevel]]]]
```

The plot produced by this code is exactly the same as the one shown above.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that `Which` is an expression that returns a value, so you could do `batterylevel[[i]] = Which[mink < next < maxk, next, next <= mink, mink, next >= maxk, maxk]` if you didn't know about `Clip`.